# VueJS/Vuetify different color chips in v-for, checking against an object with argument: color using dot notation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, computed-properties

I'm trying to set the colors of a `v-chip` by using a method, passing an argument and trying to use dot notation to return a color string:

```
<v-chip :color="stateColor(bug.workflow_state)" text-color="white">{{ bug.workflow_state }}</v-chip>
```

The right value is being passed to the method. My `argument: color` object looks like this...

```
stateColors: {
  open: 'green',
  accepted: 'yellow',
  in_progress: 'orange'
}
```

...set in the data function. I want to be able to just return a la:

```
stateColor (bugState) {
  return this.stateColors.bugState
}
```

but the `this.stateColors.bugState` is undefined. The workflow_states being passed in will all match the keys, with no exceptions. This seems like it'd be more appropriate as a computed property, but I was also having issues with the dot notation returning the expected result. My attempt was like so:

```
stateColor: function () {
  return function (bugState) {
    return this.stateColors.bugState
  }
}
```

In both attempts, `this.stateColors.open` does return green, but `this.stateColors.bugState` where bugState is actually 'open' returns undefined. `typeof(bugState)` is definitely a string. Just looking for a clean way to achieve this without a slew of if checks, which I know would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just asking for the `bugState` property, which probably doesn't exist.

Instead, ask for the key matching your `bugState` variable:

```
return this.stateColors[bugState]
```

Comment: I literally just found that. Thanks a million though!